# Running two django instances using WSGI/Apache on localhost

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, apache-config, django-wsgi

I have a web portal that fetches data from another data server(HTTP based) which I need to test on my local machine.

In production, multiple versions of the web portal will exist, but fewer of the data servers.

Here is my WSGI configuration

```
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi

WSGIDaemonProcess portal 
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/rep/portal/wsgi/wsgi.py
<Location />
        WSGIProcessGroup portal
</Location>

WSGIDaemonProcess dal 
WSGIScriptAlias /dal /home/rep/dal/wsgi/wsgi.py
<Location /dal>
        WSGIProcessGroup dal
</Location>
```

The portal code tries to fetch JSON data using a URL like `http://localhost/dal/api/foo?bar=baz`

The DAL server serves only the URL pattern

```
url(r'^/api/(?P<apiName>[a-zA-Z]+)', 'dal.dbapi.apiHandler'),
```

When I open `http://127.0.0.1/` I get the portal main page.

When I open `http://127.0.0.1/dal/foo?bar=baz` I get the 404 page of the portal instead of JSON data from the dal app

I tried configuring virtual hosts, different ports and all, but I can't get this to work properly.

In production, these servers may be on different machines, but I need to be able to test both on my localhost during development.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out...

If you do not set a WSGIProcessGroup attribute, making recursive requests will end up on the wrong django instance.

So for each VirtualHost set a unique WSGIProcessGroup